# Setting Width of ComboBox Drop Down to Exclude Scrollviewer Width

Tags: wpf, data-binding, combobox, wpf-controls

Is there an elegant way to set the width of the combobox drop down to exclude the width of the scrollviewer scroll bar and get rid of that annoying overhang?

I've tried `ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"` and `ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"` but can't seem to get rid of the overhang.

I really don't want to hard code the width. I currently have my DataTemplate object (grid) width binding to the Actual Width of the Combobox.

[Example of Overhang](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4pKkH.png)

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cboActiveLocation" Margin="25,10,25,0" Grid.Row="1" FontSize="72" VerticalAlignment="Top" MaxDropDownHeight="450" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
                    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid Margin="0 20" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=cboActiveLocation}">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                // Display Info
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ComboBox>
```

Here is the link to a similar question a few years back suggesting to bind the width like I show above but the update on that question remains unanswered.
[Setting MaxWidth of ComboboxItem such that Items width don't exceed ComboboxWidth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5221601/setting-maxwidth-of-comboboxitem-such-that-items-width-dont-exceed-comboboxwidt)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting MaxWidth of ComboboxItem such that Items width don't exceed ComboboxWidth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5221601/setting-maxwidth-of-comboboxitem-such-that-items-width-dont-exceed-comboboxwidt)

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't. There is an update on that questions which poses the same question I am asking. So perhaps its a duplicate question still and I should remove this question? I'm new to posting on SO. Regardless neither question was answered. Thank you though!